# Do two images from a docker-compose.yml file have one IP address?

Tags: docker

If I combine images inside `docker-compose.yml` file, say, `nginx` and `postgres`, will they be running on a single "virtual machine", e.g. share the same IP address?

Is it be correct to call one image from another one as 'localhost'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. nginx and postgres won't share one localhost.

A quite senseless example that clarifies things:

```
#docker-compose.yml:
version: '3'
services:
    postgres:
        image: postgres
    nginx:
        image: nginx
```

Then run: `docker-compose up -d && docker-compose exec postgres ping -c 3 nginx && docker-compose down`

A good starting point is https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/